# Unmount, or hide in React?

Tags: javascript, dom, optimization, reactjs

What's more efficient? Should I mount and unmount components, or show and hide them with css?

The practical case where this has come up for me is with Modals. I can either keep the Modal's 'active' state in its parent component, and pass it along as a prop to the Modal which then maybe applies className 'active'. Or, I could have a modal 'navigator' that determines which modal to display, and its reference gets passed around to other components.

Comment: Found this relevant question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12079345/which-is-one-more-expensive-to-call-showing-hiding-a-dom-node-or-creating-delet I am still curious if React's virtual dom has any effect on this

Comment: I would prefer hide by removing component, just because if it uses states from model, it would be not updated in case it hidden and so render or update will not be called for update something that hidden.

Comment: Using CSS might be easier if you want to animate the component leaving/entering. Though you can use `ReactCSSTransitionGroup` for this as well. If you don't want to animate, don't render it at all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a matter of preference, but I always `return null` if I don't need an item to be visible.

The main reason is that if you're doing server-side rendering, and you have a few hundred lines of HTML that is 'hidden' but still gets rendered, then you're sending a lot of unnecessary data over the wire.

A modal 'navigator' (or 'conductor' below) would sit as the last child at the top of your DOM tree and return the appropriate modal or null:

```
import React from 'react';

import ExportDataModal from './ExportDataModal.jsx';
import SignInModal from './SignInModal.jsx';
import FeedbackModal from './FeedbackModal.jsx';
import BoxDetailsModal from './BoxDetailsModal.jsx';

const ModalConductor = props => {
  switch (props.currentModal) {
    case 'EXPORT_DATA':
      return <ExportDataModal {...props}/>;

    case 'SOCIAL_SIGN_IN':
      return <SignInModal {...props}/>;

    case 'FEEDBACK':
      return <FeedbackModal {...props}/>;

    case 'EDIT_BOX':
      return <BoxDetailsModal {...props}/>;

    default:
      return null;
  }
};

export default ModalConductor;
```

[Here's an article](https://medium.com/@david.gilbertson/modals-in-react-f6c3ff9f4701#.j6gsyjnb2) that goes into a bit of detail about Modals in React.

Comment: This is great! Thanks for the article as well, I like the approch

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I had a similar question about hiding or unmounting and was switching between multiple modals based on the screen's context.